# Showing a progress image while processing background task or submitting a form

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

I have an asp.net form.  I want to show a jquery progress image while a form is submitted and there is some stuff happening in the backend.

This is my javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#progress').hide();
    $("#ProjectNavigation input.bgdiv").click(function () {            
        $("#progress").show();
        $("body").load($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

Clicking on the either images with class set to "bgdiv" is showing the animated gif (as expected), but I want to hide the gif (or div it is wrapped around with) after backend stuff has completed processing.  Not sure how to accomplish that.  I am not sure if this line is correct in my javacsript since I dont have an href tag in my html:  $("body").load($(this).attr('href'));

Any tips are very much appreciated.

Here is my markup:

```
<table id="ProjectNavigation" class="ProjectNavigation" width="100%">
<tr>
    <td>Title 1</td><td>Title 2</td><td>Title 3</td><td>Title 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="HelpGuidanceLink">Comments
        <div id="progress" style="padding:20px 0 0 35px;">
            <img src="/_layouts/images/progress-image.gif">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td colspan="3">
        <textarea name="CommentsTextBox" rows="3" cols="20" id="CommentsTextBox" class="ProjectGuideTextBox">
            other comments testing...
        </textarea>
    </td>
</tr>    
<tr>        
    <td colspan="4">
        <input type="image" name="PreviousPhaseImageButton" id="PreviousPhaseImageButton" class="bgdiv" src="/images/previous-phase-arrow.png" />
        <input type="image" name="NextPhaseImageButton" id="NextPhaseImageButton" class="bgdiv" src="/images/next-phase-arrow.png" />            
    </td>    
</tr>
```

Thanks -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.load()` accepts a callback function as a parameter. Add a function as your second parameter in your call to load that hides the progress bar.

Regarding the href, it looks like you're right - it won't work as is. You need to tell jQuery the URL to load. It seems most natural to me to specify that in the input's value attribute and retrieve it using `.val()`.

```
$("body").load($(this).val(), function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    $('#progress').hide();
});
```

Here's a [working demo at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PuQv8/1/).

Comment: This does not work.  Am I missing something?
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#progress').hide();
    $("#ProjectNavigation input.bgdiv").click(function () {            
        $("#progress").show();        
        $("body").load($(this).val(), function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            $('#progress').hide();
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

Comment: What part doesn't work?  The content isn't loaded or the progress indicator remains?

Comment: the progress image is not loading now.

Comment: Maybe your form is being submitted. Call `e.preventDefault()` in your click handler. You'll have to add `e` as an argument to your click handler.